# What cloud storage software should I use for my company?

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-storage

I manage an estate agency.

Currently we have one office with a server (running WHS) based on-site.

On the server we have a folder for each property in our portfolio. In this folder we store marketing images, copies of contracts, etc.

At present, we all have read/write permission to this folder.

This works fine but fails when we are working outside of the office as we cannot access the server folders.

I'm looking for a cloud based system that allows us to continue operating as we do now but also from outside of the office. We want to avoid having to download a file, edit it and re-upload it to keep everything synced. What we like about our current setup is that we can navigate to the folder (using the normal Windows interface), double click a Word file, make changes, save it and everyone sees the updated file with no fuss.

I have looked into software such as Dropbox and Google Drive but they don't appear to do exactly what I'm looking for.